# Remove class when browser scrolls down but add class when it scrolls up

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm creating a 1 page website, I want to remove a class when the user scrolls down and add the class when the user scrolls up.

I've got this working to a point but it's not correct, at the moment when the user scrolls down 50px from the top then the class is removed and it's added when the user scrolls up 50px from the top.

I want it so that they can be almost at the bottom of the page and if the scroll up the class is there and if they scroll down then it's removed

Here's the query I have so far

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".test").addClass("mobile");
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= 50) {
        $(".test").removeClass("mobile");
        } else if (scroll <= 50) {
        $(".test").addClass("mobile");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So this declares a global variable lastScroll to track the last known scroll position. After the user scrolls, it will compare the scroll location to the last known scroll location and add or remove your class depending on that. I also removed the <= and >= because I didn't want it to do anything if the scroll position doesn't change (somehow).

```
var lastScroll = 0;

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".test").addClass("mobile");

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll > lastScroll) {
            $(".test").removeClass("mobile");
        } else if (scroll < lastScroll) {
            $(".test").addClass("mobile");
        }
        lastScroll = scroll;
    });
});
```

Per the comments below, add this:

```
var lastScroll = 0;

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".test").addClass("mobile");

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        setTimeout(function() { //give them a second to finish scrolling before doing a check
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scroll > lastScroll + 30) {
                $(".test").removeClass("mobile");
            } else if (scroll < lastScroll - 30) {
                $(".test").addClass("mobile");
            }
            lastScroll = scroll;
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: @C Bauer Sorry for the late reply. It works perfectly thank you,  i've marked it as answered but... how would i edit it so that the user has to scroll up slightly say 30px instead?

Comment: You could do `if(scroll > lastScroll + 30) {...} else if(scroll < lastScroll - 30) {...}`, but I'd be worried that this new method might not react nicely... I'll add another code block.